# show progress bar loader according to server process done

Tags: node.js, express

how to show progress bar loader depend on a server process in client side. suppose client clicked on the download button then server receive request after that server find data from table user in database1(suppose a thousand records in table user)  and copy it to database2( table user ) and it total time required to find from database1 and copy into another database is 1 min .in my case I have lots of table and data. now my problem is that if I just show loading icon then user got confused (he/she might think that process get stuck) another thing  is that if I just show progress bar loader with hardcode time(suppose 1 min ) in client side then what if process time get increase in server then also user got confused.

let me show some sample code

```
** // copy data from database1**
var variant = await varianttable.find();
var user = await usertable.find();
var product = await producttable.find();
var sale = await saletable.find();
var tansfer = await tansfertable.find();


** // paste data in database2**
try {
    await varianttable.create(variant[0])
    await usertable.create(user[0])
    await producttable.create(product[0])
    await saletable.create(sale[0])
    await tansfertable.create(tansfer[0])

} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

**what I want** is that if server done copying  data from all table in database1 then it should 50% process complete in client-side and after pasting data in database2 progress bar should show 100 complete in client side during googling I found that I can use socket.io can anyone tell me how I can use in the above code  or is there any alternative method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use socket.io to achieve this.

What you need to do create a channel per user on socket.io and then push progress on that channel from back-end. Also I would suggest use following progress bar flow instead of directly jumping to 50% and than 100%.

```
// Push to client using socket.io (10%)
socket.emit('USER_CHANNEL_NAME', 10); ** // copy data from database1**
var variant = await varianttable.find();
var user = await usertable.find();
socket.emit('USER_CHANNEL_NAME', 25);
var product = await producttable.find();
var sale = await saletable.find();
var tansfer = await tansfertable.find();
socket.emit('USER_CHANNEL_NAME', 50);

** // paste data in database2**
try {
    await varianttable.create(variant[0])
    await usertable.create(user[0])
    await producttable.create(product[0])
    socket.emit('USER_CHANNEL_NAME', 70);
    await saletable.create(sale[0])
    socket.emit('USER_CHANNEL_NAME', 85);
    await tansfertable.create(tansfer[0])
    socket.emit('USER_CHANNEL_NAME', 100);
    // Here if you are sending response to server.
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

It's pretty easy to setup socket.io just go through their official site and Get started guide and you should be good to implement it.

> More about socket.io at https://socket.io